# Errno 32 Broken pipe, Errno 107 Transport endpoint is not connected python socket

Tags: python, apache, tcp, broken-pipe, sigpipe

My TCP Server is written in Qt 4.7, works well with TCP Client also written in Qt 4.7.

I am trying to connect and communicate with Server with client written in python 2.7.3. I start the Server process via apache http request with `subprocess.call(path_to_server)`. I am using mod_wsgi 3.3 and django 1.4.

Connection is established without a problem. I am receiving `[Errno 32] Broken pipe` exception on `socket.send()` randomly (I can spam same msg for 10 times and it will be sent 0-10 times). Same happens to `socket.shutdown()` & `socket.close()`, I can spam disconnect command and it will randomly disconnect, otherwise receiving `[Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected` exception.

netstat -nap says connection is established.

When I try running same client script using python2.7 shell everything works fine.

What am I missing here?

`EDIT`
Everything works on Windows 7, running same apache,mod_wsgi,python,django configuration. TCP Server is also Windows compatible. Error happens on centos6.2 32bit.

Comment: Checking out apache settings, KeepAlive and KeepAliveRequests specially. Seems promising, will report later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set apache settings to following:
`KeepAlive On` 
`MaxKeepAliveRequests 0`
`KeepAliveTimeout 5`

I will further investigate the problem and see if this is proper solution.